# How to deserialise WCF message

Tags: wcf, rest, serialization

I have a messsage interceptor in my WCF REST application that im using to log messages. This is being returned to the client

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Binary>77u/PD94bWwgUTVweDs /*snip */ +PC9IVE1MPg==</Binary>
```

Which gets deserialised by fiddler to something readable. How can I decode the binary data into something readable myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binary data appears to be base64 encoded.

Use `Convert.FromBase64String` to decode.